# Is it expected behaviour that CMake does not exit upon error in string(JSON ...) with no ERROR_VARIABLE argument?

Tags: cmake, ubuntu-22.04

I use CMAKE on Ubuntu 22.
I have the following CMAKE code:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
<...snip...>
# Read the configuration file
file(READ "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/config.json" CONFIG)
string(JSON SW_VER_MAJOR GET ${CONFIG} SW VER_MAJOR)
string(JSON SW_VER_MINOR GET ${CONFIG} SW VER_MINOR)
string(JSON SW_BUILD GET ${CONFIG} SW BUILD)

message(STATUS "SW version: ${SW_VER_MAJOR}.${SW_VER_MINOR}.${SW_BUILD}")

add_compile_definitions(_VER_MAJOR=${SW_VER_MAJOR})
add_compile_definitions(_VER_MINOR=${SW_VER_MINOR})
add_compile_definitions(_VER_BUILD=${SW_BUILD})
```

When one of the parameters is missing in the JSON file, I get the error like:

```
 CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:41 (string):
 string sub-command JSON member 'SW_VER_MAJOR' not found.
```

After the error, the CMAKE build continues.
I expect that this error will be a fatal error and CMAKE will stop.
According to doc https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html
If the ERROR_VARIABLE optional parameter is not defined, the error should be handled as a fatal error.
But actually, it is not happening.
What I did wrong?

Comment: I've reached out the maintainers about this and will write an answer post about my findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a known issue with CMake; see this ticket from 2021: https://discourse.cmake.org/t/fatal-errors-not-halting-processing/3752/7